# c++ how to deal with method returning either NULL or std::string?

Tags: c++

I am a bit stuck with some code. I have to use the return type of the method `getToto()` which usually returns a `std::string`, but in one case it returns `false` (It is part of a library I have to use, I cannot modify it). I understand that is equivalent to a null pointer. But I cannot find a proper way to catch it!

**Test.cpp**

```cpp
static std::string getToto(){
 char buffer[1024];
 if ( CTX_Get_Env(buffer, "Toto", 1024) )
    return false;
 return buffer;
}
```

If I try

```cpp
const char* returned = Test::getToto().c_str();
if (returned==NULL){
    std::cout<< "null pointer"<<std::endl;
}
```

I get an error whilst running

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>
> what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid

Sorry, I have a rather low level in C++.

Comment: If `getToto` is part of a library that you cannot modify, then the best you can do is to file a bug report with your library vendor.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Is returning an empty string part of the logic, or is it an exceptional condition.

If it's not supposed to happen, you should throw an error.

If it's okay for the string to be empty, you should just return an empty string:

```
 return std::string();
```

The reason it compiles as-is is that `false` is interpreted as `0`, which is `NULL`, which can be a `char*`, so a string is attempted to be constructed from it. However, constructing an `std::string` from a `NULL` pointer is invalid, that's why you're getting the exception.

Here's how I'd code it:

```
static std::string getToto(){
   char buffer[1024];
   if ( CTX_Get_Env(buffer, "Toto", 1024) )
      throw InvalidDataInBufferException();
   return buffer;
}
```

if the string isn't supposed to be empty, or

```
static std::string getToto(){
   char buffer[1024];
   if ( CTX_Get_Env(buffer, "Toto", 1024) )
      return std::string();
   return buffer;
}
```

if it's okay for the string to be empty.

Comment: @user1839362 okay. Did you try setting the `Toto` environment variable?

Answer (score 3):

The implicit `std::string(const char*)` constructor is being initialized with `false`, which is being interpreted as the null pointer. Constructing an `std::string` from a null pointer is disallowed by the standard. On your platform,  this results in an exception being thrown. If you cannot modify the function, you can place the function call inside of a try block, but note that **this is by no means guaranteed to work on other platforms**.

```
try {
  std::string returned = Test::getToto().c_str();
  const char* c = returned.c_str();
} catch(...) {
  // handle the error
}
```

**Note 1**: Since implementations are not required to raise an exception if an `std::string` is initialized from a null pointer, calling the `getToto()` function can result in undefined behaviour. The `try-catch` blocks only help if your implementation throws an exception, and is therefore not a portable solution. This also means that the library function `getToto()`, by invoking undefined behaviour, should be avoided.

**Note2**: The exception was hiding another error, here:

```
const char* returned = Test::getToto().c_str();
```

`Test::getToto()` returns a temporary string, which you do not assign. Your `returned` pointer is left dangling. In my code example, I assign the return to an `std::string`, *then* get the pointer to its internal char data.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the answer has resulted in a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Mat ah, didn't see that part.

Comment: The temporary `std::string` will be destroyed, leaving `returned` as a dangling pointer.

Comment: No problem. BTW, is it guaranteed that `std::logic_error` is thrown? The standard states this: _Requires: s shall not be a null pointer_.

Comment: @hmjd Actually, I cannot see any requirement to throw an exception, let alone `std::logic_error` (which is what I get with GCC).

Comment: I would have expected this to be undefined behaviour. If it is not specified by the standard that an exception be thrown then there is no portable way to fix this given the `getToto()` function is unmodifiable and forever broken.

Comment: ok thanks for the tips and explanations! For the moment I will use the try catch possibility and ask for a modification of the library :)

Comment: It is unquestionably undefined behavior. The implementation is simply taking advantage of that in order to very nicely throw an exception. @user1839362 If you cannot modify the function then what you can do about this is ensure that the line `return false;` is _never_ executed. Either you should not use the library function at all, or you should somehow ensure that `CTX_Get_Env()` cannot ever fail.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to catch the exception as that won't fix the problem on other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that you got an exception BEFORE even getToto() really returns. There is no way to do 'return false' from the function returning string and do not get an exception. It's just a bug.
You can override it with try/catch block like this:

```
const char* returned = NULL;
try{
    returned = Test::getToto().c_str();
}catch(std::exception& e){
    std::cout << "null pointer" << std::endl;
}
```

but it is still a BAD thing to do.